# in scala,how to get the collect the values in Iterable[(Tuple)]

Tags: scala, rdd, iterable

I have an `RDD[(Key,Iterable[(Name,Value)])]`.
I am trying to get all the values in `Name` so that I can get all the unique occurrences of `Name` and then create an `Index` so I can create a resulting `RDD` of `RDD[(Key,Iterable[(Index,Value)])]`.

Input examples:

```
(4048,CompactBuffer(("a",3.0), ("b",9.0), ("c",14.0))
(4049,CompactBuffer(("a",2.0), ("c",14.0))
(4050,CompactBuffer(("b",2.0), ("d",10.0))
```

Output examples:

```
(4048,CompactBuffer((1,3.0), (2,9.0), (3,14.0))
(4049,CompactBuffer((1,2.0), (3,12.0))
(4050,CompactBuffer((2,2.0), (4,10.0))
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, something like this should work:

```
val rdd: RDD[K, Iterable[N, V]] = ???

val nameIndexMap = rdd.flatMap(_._2.map(nv => nv._1))
                      .distinct
                      .collect
                      .zipWithIndex
                      .toMap

val newRDD = rdd.mapValues(xs => xs.map(nv => (nameIndexMap(nv._1), nv._2)))
```

If `nameIndexMap` is large or will be used multiple times, then you might want to use a broadcast, e.g. something like this

```
val nameIndexMapBc = sc.broadcast(nameIndexMap)  //sc is the SparkContext

val newRDD = rdd.mapValues(xs => xs.map(nv => (nameIndexMap.value)(nv._1), nv._2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to jasonl's anwer in case of high cardinality of name space you can perform similar transformation avoiding collecting names to driver memory:

```
val named = rdd.flatMap { case (key, values) => values.map { case (name, value) => (name, (key, value)) } }

val nameMap = named.map(_._1).distinct().zipWithUniqueId()

val indexed = named.join(nameMap).map { case (name, ((key, value), index)) => (key, (index, value)) }.groupByKey
```